# Suspicious Amount of Zeros in Confusion Matrix

Tags: svm, naive-bayes, k-nearest-neighbour, confusion-matrix

I have a data set with about 45000 observations and three features. When I apply machine learning classification algorithms like naive Bayes, kNN and SVM I receive a lot of zeros in the resulting confusion matrix.

In particular for naive Bayes and SVM with linear, polynomial and sigmoid kernel (with `e1071` R package) I receive a confusion matrix like following:

```
pred   aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee  fff  ggg  hhh
  aaa 1639 2888 2985 2945 2174 1345 1549 1648
  bbb  137  217  236  290  272  239  426  156
  ccc    0    0   41    0    0    0    0    0
  ddd    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  eee    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  fff    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  ggg    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   55
  hhh  671  787  940  702    0  442  122 1945
```

For kNN (with `kknn` R package) and SVM radial kernel the confusion matrix looks more non-suspicious.

```
pred   aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee  fff  ggg  hhh
  aaa  749  593  736  352   68  208  413  273
  bbb  393 1742 1076 1246  662  916  789  924
  ccc  322  235 1002  191  420   64   90  127
  ddd   26   29   45   79   94   69    5   34
  eee    3  239   44  363  476  299  170    5
  fff   42  112   56  386   90   15  307   73
  ggg  346   54  503  636   99   99  258   57
  hhh  566  888  740  684  537  356   65 2311
```

Is there maybe a problem with the complexity of the data set or is this just the *correct* classification result?