# Confusion Matrix values of zero

Tags: multivariate-analysis, discriminant-analysis, confusion-matrix

My question is almost exaclty the same as this one: [Suspicious Amount of Zeros in Confusion Matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153183/suspicious-amount-of-zeros-in-confusion-matrix), but no one seems to have responded so I figure I'll ask again.

I've got a LOO confusion matrix that looks like this resulting from LDA on 271 samples from these 4 areas:

```
Overall accuracy  Prior frequency.England   Prior frequency.France 
   0.6407                   0.3815                   0.1111 
Prior frequency.Scotland    Prior frequency.Wales 
        0.3185                   0.1889 

          Predicted (cv)
Actual     England France Scotland  Wales
  England   0.6602 0.0000   0.3204 0.0194
  France    0.0667 0.0000   0.6333 0.3000
  Scotland  0.1744 0.0116   0.6977 0.1163
  Wales     0.0392 0.0000   0.0784 0.8824
```

Here's a second confusion matrix function's output for the same analysis with more details:

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction England France Scotland Wales
  England       68      0       33     2
  France         2      0       19     9
  Scotland      15      1       60    10
  Wales          2      0        4    45

Overall Statistics

               Accuracy : 0.6407         
                 95% CI : (0.5804, 0.698)
    No Information Rate : 0.4296         
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 2.392e-12      

                  Kappa : 0.4821         
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 2.183e-06      

Statistics by Class:

                     Class: England Class: France Class: Scotland Class: Wales
Sensitivity                  0.7816      0.000000          0.5172       0.6818
Specificity                  0.8087      0.888476          0.8312       0.9706
Pos Pred Value               0.6602      0.000000          0.6977       0.8824
Neg Pred Value               0.8862      0.995833          0.6957       0.9041
Prevalence                   0.3222      0.003704          0.4296       0.2444
Detection Rate               0.2519      0.000000          0.2222       0.1667
Detection Prevalence         0.3815      0.111111          0.3185       0.1889
Balanced Accuracy            0.7952      0.444238          0.6742       0.8262
```

There are a total of 30 samples from France, so that the column of zeros is rather unnerving.  I'm a complete beginner at this, so I've really got no clue if this makes sense - I can't find anything about having too many zeros on this site or stats textbooks I'm using, so I'm hoping someone here can offer some insight.

If I'm interpreting this correctly, this would mean that no French sample was predicted to be from France (which is fine, I guess), but it just has warning bells going off in my head.  Is it possible that not a single sample would be present at the intersection between the French column (predicted) and the French Row (actual)?

Comment: Your diagnosis about no `France` samples being predicted as such is correct (= zero true positives for this class). Do you obtain the confusion matrix from the same data or different data as you trained your model on? Are your classes balanced/could you add the absolute values of your confusion matrix?

Comment: @geekoverdose - the first matrix was from the training set, but I've added the LOO matrix and another function's output with more information.  I can add the training set's matrix again if needed.  I'm afraid a quick scan of Google couldn't turn up what "absolute values" are in relation to confusion matrices, so I'd be more than happy to add them if you can elaborate on what they are. Thanks!

Comment: You already added the absolute values in the second confusion matrix ;) Now there is one `Scotland` sample that is classified as `France` (false positive for this class). Do I understand correctly that with "LOO" you mean "leave one out (cross validation)", and that you therefore test the model on one sample it has not seen before each time?

Comment: Correct on both accounts - in the initial post I had the training set confusion matrix that recorded no `France` values, so the results are very similar, but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that those results are in fact correct, and that they are caused by a strange/difficult distribution of samples for the `France` class.

As you use results from LOOCV it could be that your model is just not able to predict any unseen sample from samples it has seen during training. This could be caused by e.g. the `France` class having a strange/difficult to model distribution for `LDA` (one could construct such distributions for many classifiers), or that you have too little data for modelling such a distribution. Another explanation would be that just you got erroneous data in the first place (e.g. switched or wrong labels).

Consequently, you could/should now:

1. Double check that you did not get erroneous data if this is possible for you.
2. Use your domain specific knowledge about the data to check if the results for the `France` class could actually make sense (is there any reason that this class could be so different? Different recording conditions, different context, ...). Try to investigate the features and feature-target relation - maybe you find something that would explain your results.
3. Try other models. You will likely get very different results using e.g. a KNN or tree/forest based model instead. If this is true, this again tells you something about your data, and which be able to give you a better understanding of point 2.

Comment: Thanks for the insight - it actually makes sense for this to happen (regarding your second point), and I'll double check my coding even though I'm pretty sure it's correct (your first point).  Point three is a bit scary, but I'll give it a whirl.  This is exactly the kind of helpful answer I needed for beginner-level guidance!